# UIKit dynamics to interact with particles

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, particles, uikit-dynamics

Is there anyway for particles created in UIKit to interact with each other? I was thinking it doesn't have to be shown on screen with UIKit dynamics, but it can just be position with "collision" detection so it can have effects when it enters the "collision boundaries" of another object.

But it would be great if it (particles) can be affected by gravity and such...